# Matching two lists of nonequivalent length and appending matches to new list

Tags: python, list, dataframe, append

I have 2 lists and a DF: Indiana Zip Codes, Ohio Zip Codes, and gift purchaser zip codes (the data frame). There are 348 Indiana zip codes, 227 Ohio zip codes, and 6,000 purchaser zip codes (some of which are not Ohio or Indiana based)

I want to find all the matching zip codes in the purchaser dataframe and see if there is a match to any zip codes in indiana or ohio zip code list, if there is then append the entire row of the purchaser list to the respective state list

```
purchaser_zip = purchasers['zip']
indiana_zip = indiana['zip']
ohio_zip = ohio['zip']

ohio_match = []
indiana_match = []

for i in purchaser_zip:
    if i == indiana_zip.any():
        indiana_match.append(i)

for i in purchaser_zip:
    if i == ohio_zip.any():
        ohio_match.append(i)
```

I would use the join method, but these are lists of unequal length. And I am only returned with an empty list

Comment: Those look like Series, not lists, assuming that all the base objects are pandas dfs.

Comment: `indiana_zip.any()` just checks is any element is non-falsy. Since it returns a boolean, it will never be equal to `i`, which is not a boolean. Did you mean `(indiana_zip == i).any()`?

Comment: You are right. I was having no fill to the list because I was comparing objects to ints. You are right too, I am looking past the boolean and obtaining the actual rows from purchasers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin`:

```
indiana_match = purchasers[purchasers['zip'].isin(indiana_zip)]
ohio_match = purchasers[purchasers['zip'].isin(ohio_zip)]
```